# A form with 2 columns using Material Design Lite

Tags: html, forms

This is my code which renders a form:I want field1 and field2 to be in line with the bold headings(right and left) also the text fields to be closer to the labels(fields) I am using the grid component of MDL< I tried putting column numbers as 0,1,5 in the  for the mdl cell.. but I don't get my desired layout. I first tried without nesting fields under the headings but that din't work either so now i have nested them. Is there anther way?

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mdl-grid">
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col padding-top-bottom0"><strong>LEFT</strong>
                    <div class="mdl-grid padding-top-bottom0 b-form">
                        <div class="mdl-cell">Field1</div>
                        <div class="mdl-cell">
                            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield margin-top-bottom0 padding-top-bottom0" style="width: 100% !important;">
                                <input class="mdl-textfield__input b-form-input" type="text"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mdl-grid padding-top-bottom0 b-form">
                        <div class="mdl-cell">Field2</div>
                        <div class="mdl-cell">
                            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield margin-top-bottom0 padding-top-bottom0" style="width: 100% !important;">
                                <input class="mdl-textfield__input b-form-input" type="text"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col padding-top-bottom0"><strong>RIGHT</strong>
                    <div class="mdl-grid padding-top-bottom0 b-form">
                        <div class="mdl-cell">Field1</div>
                        <div class="mdl-cell">
                            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield margin-top-bottom0 padding-top-bottom0" style="width: 100% !important;">
                                <input class="mdl-textfield__input b-form-input" type="text"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mdl-grid padding-top-bottom0 b-form">
                        <div class="mdl-cell">Field2</div>
                        <div class="mdl-cell">
                            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield margin-top-bottom0 padding-top-bottom0" style="width: 100% !important;">
                                <input class="mdl-textfield__input b-form-input" type="text"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                    </div><!-- closing grid -->
```

[image: This is a screen shot of the output.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the html to:

Left side
`<div class="mdl-cell"><div class="mdl-cell"><strong>LEFT</strong></div></div>`

Right side
`<div class="mdl-cell"><div class="mdl-cell"><strong>LEFT</strong></div></div>`

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2EaKD/424/

Comment: Thank you:) I think this will help me move the text fields closer, along with lining up the fields which your code is already doing.